# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, syntax-error

I have a list of URL's where I'm scraping title name of each page by looping the entire list of URLs

The problem is whenever the url is invalid in the list the code is breaking up. so I'm trying to use **try** and **except** to pass the error how ever try and except is not working

Below is the code i'm using,(Please correct if I'm missing something here)

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
    url_list = ['http://www.aurecongroup.com',
    'http://www.bendigoadelaide.com.au',
    'http://www.burrell.com.au',
    'http://www.dsdbi.vic.gov.au',
    'http://www.energyaustralia.com.au',
    'http://www.executiveboard.com',
    'http://www.mallesons.com',
    'https://www.minterellison.com',
    'http://www.mta.org.nz',
    'http://www.services.nsw.gov.au']

for link in url_list:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link)    
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        html_content = r.text
        soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')
        df = soup.title.string
        print(df)

    except IOError:
        pass
```

Executing the above code is giving me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'`. 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hint: capitalization matters, and indentation matters.

Comment: might be just a typo but `try` is all lowercase and you have indentation problem in your `for` loop. Apparently it's not a typo since fixing that works.

Comment: Also, if you want processing to continue when one element fails, you would need to move your `try...except` *inside* the `for` block, wrapping the loop body.

Comment: @ryancha could you please help me with the code to proceed further when one element fails in the loop

Comment: @COLDSPEED posted an answer that should help with that scenario.

Comment: @MaheshVarma You have unmarked my answer. Is there something the matter with it?

Comment: Hi @COLDSPEED I'm getting this error in the middle while i'm running the code " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = [
    'http://www.aurecongroup.com',
    'http://www.bendigoadelaide.com.au',
    'http://www.burrell.com.au',
    'http://www.dsdbi.vic.gov.au',
    'http://www.energyaustralia.com.au',
    'http://www.executiveboard.com',
    'http://www.mallesons.com',
    'https://www.minterellison.com',
    'http://www.mta.org.nz',
    'http://www.services.nsw.gov.au'
    ]

for link in url_list:   
    try:
        res = requests.get(link)    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        try:
            df = soup.title.string.strip()
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            df = ""

        print(df)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Partial output including none:

```
Aurecon – A global engineering and infrastructure advisory company
                                         ####It gives the none value
Stockbroking & Superannuation Brisbane | Burrell
Home | Economic Development
Electricity Providers - Gas Suppliers | EnergyAustralia
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your `try-catch` *into* the loop, if you want *only that* erroneous iteration skipped.

```
for link in url_list:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link)    
        ...
    except (IOError, AttributeError):
        pass
```

Comment: Hi @COLDSPEED I'm getting this error in the middle while i'm running the code " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'"

Comment: @MaheshVarma Made an edit. Any further questions go into a new post. If this helped, don't forget to vote on, and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MaheshVarma if you’re going to unmark my answer, I’d appreciate an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 2):

Execute this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url_list = ['Http://www.aurecongroup.com',
'Http://www.burrell.com.au',
'Http://www.dsdbi.vic.gov.au',
'Http://www.energyaustralia.com.au',
'Http://www.executiveboard.com',
'Http://www.mallesons.com',
'Https://www.minterellison.com',
'Http://www.mta.org.nz',
'Http://www.services.nsw.gov.au']

try:
    for link in url_list:
        r = requests.get(link)    
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        html_content = r.text
        soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')
        df = soup.title.string
        print(df)

except IOError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try:` should be lowercase `try:`. And miss tabulation after `for link in url_list:`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url_list = ['Http://www.aurecongroup.com',
            'Http://www.burrell.com.au',
            'Http://www.dsdbi.vic.gov.au',
            'Http://www.energyaustralia.com.au',
            'Http://www.executiveboard.com',
            'Http://www.mallesons.com',
            'Https://www.minterellison.com',
            'Http://www.mta.org.nz',
            'Http://www.services.nsw.gov.au']

try:
    for link in url_list:
        r = requests.get(link)
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        html_content = r.text
        soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')
        df = soup.title.string
        print(df)

except IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: No additional contribution compared to the answer provided earlier. You're invited to contribute in improving the previous answer.

Answer (score -1):

## **This fixes the INDENT ERROR**

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url_list = [
    'Http://www.aurecongroup.com',
    'Http://www.burrell.com.au',
    'Http://www.dsdbi.vic.gov.au',
    'Http://www.energyaustralia.com.au',
    'Http://www.executiveboard.com',
    'Http://www.mallesons.com',
    'Https://www.minterellison.com',
    'Http://www.mta.org.nz',
    'Http://www.services.nsw.gov.au'
]

try:
    for link in url_list:
        r = requests.get(link)    
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        html_content = r.text
        soup = BS(html_content, 'lxml')
        df = soup.title.string
        print(df)

except IOError:
    pass
```

Comment: This is no different than the code in the question!

Comment: This does not appear to fix anything. The only difference I see between this and the original is a newline after the imports.

Comment: @ryancha could you please help me with the code to proceed further when one element fails in the loop